# Laravel, get two functions

Tags: php, laravel

I would like some help, Within the "*users*" table I have the structure "*referrer_id*", "*name*" and "*active*". In this function below I can only get the names of the users in the "*users*" table, how can I also get the status  "*active*"?

```
public function nnIndicaded() {

   return implode('<li>', User::where('referrer_id', $this->id)->pluck('name')->all());



}
```

Comment: you want where user status is active??

Comment: I would like to know where I can implement "active" inside the script next to "name"

Comment: Have you tried this? `User::select( 'name', 'active' )->where('referrer_id', $this->id)...`

Comment: "User::Select" would not work for me, I need "User::Where" and also "pluck"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go the way matticustard has suggested.

However, sometimes it can be messy to change the structure of a big project when you just need some small modifications. If your goal is to only get those users who are with "active" status and do not want to modify the current structure too much, you could do:

```
public function nnIndicaded() {
   return "<li>".implode(' active</li>,<li>', User::where(['referrer_id' => $this->id, 'status' => 'active'])->pluck('name')->all())."</li>";
}
```

Also if you decide to go matticustard way, you dont need to select all, you can just get name and status, if thats the only properties you need like so:

```
$users = User::where('referrer_id', $this->id)->select('name','status')->get();
```

Based upon your comment, it looks like you have DB field as "Active" which is 1 for active users and 0 for inactive users. Also I see you would like to fetch inactive users list separately as well.

So for that, you can pass a parameter to the function like so:

```
public function nnIndicaded($active=null) {
   $where = ['referrer_id' => $this->id];
   if ($active !== null) {
       $where['Active'] = $active;
   }
   return "<li>".implode(' active</li>,<li>', User::where($where)->pluck('name')->all())."</li>";
}
```

Then:

- `nnIndicaded(1)` will return active users
- `nnIndicaded(0)` will return inactive users
- `nnIndicaded()` will return all users

Comment: Thanks, it works, I just changed 'Status' by the name of my structure 'Active', but only shows the active users, as would the inactive ones? In my database 'Active' is '1' and if inactive it will be '0'

 return implode(' active</li>,<li>', User::where(['referrer_id' => $this->id, 'active' => 'active'])->pluck('name')->all());

Comment: Yes thanks! now as it would be for inactive users as it is only looking for the active ones

Comment: @AtilaOliveira Updated my answer, based upon your comment, feel free to upvote it if it resolves your issue

Comment: Top!!! but would it be a lot of work if it were all in one search? Active and inactive all together.

Comment: @AtilaOliveira You can tweak the function to return all users also. See the updated answer

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you would split this between your controller and blade.

**SomeController.php**

```php
public function index() 
{
   $users = User::where('referrer_id', $this->id)->get();

   // or get only active status
   // $users = User::where('referrer_id', $this->id)->where('status', 'active')->get();

   return view('some.layout',['users' => $users]);
}
```

**some/layout.blade.php**

```php
<ul>
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        <li>{{ $user->name }} {{ $user->status }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: The function that I mentioned in the post search users who are registered below other users ie "indicated", the name obtained I already have, now I need to get the status "active"

Comment: My post shows you both how to display the user status within your HTML and also how to search by status — see the alternate query commented out above.  I don't understand what else you are asking for.

Comment: For example, if you signed up through my link, and someone signed up through your (referral) link, I would like to get the status of who signed up via your (referral) link. Your code is correct, but it only shows your status and not the user who registered with your (referenced) link.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "my" status.  This shows the status of each individual user queried from the database.  If you want to compare these records in some way to other records, you will need a relationship.